# How to put input field hidden value in asp button

Tags: asp.net

I have hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="<%=orderRef%>" />
```

and I have a asp button, and i want to pass this param to aspx.cs function:

```
<asp:Button ID="submitForFree" runat="server" OnCommand="btnPromoBtn_Click" CommandArgument="<%=orderRef%>" class="primary-button" Text="PayNow"></asp:Button>
```

but in the function it show me a string "<%=orderRef%>"
How can i put it in CommandArgument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

### Set it in the code behind

Instead of trying to set it in the markup, set it in your codebehind, some time after OnInit.

```
this.submitForFree.CommandArgument = orderRef;
```

### Read it from the request

Instead of passing the value in CommandArgument, just read it from the HttpRequest, where the hidden variable is exposed in `Request.Form`.

```
protected void btnPromoBtn_Click(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    //var arg = e.CommandArgument;
    var arg = Request.Form["orderRef"];
    DoSomethingWithCommandArgument(arg);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't he/she need a `runat="server"` attribute for `input tag`?

Comment: No not for the raw hidden input.

Comment: But if he added the attribute, he will be able to use it like that :
`var arg = orderRef.Value;` 
am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `CommandArgument` like this:

```
CommandArgument='<%# orderRef %>'
```

But if your button is outside a Repeater, GridView, ListView etc you need to call `DataBind` manually every time the page is loaded.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    submitForFree.DataBind();
}
```